# Weird behavior using org.geotools Filter

Tags: java, geotools

I am using filter to catch all the features who fall into a specific polygon. My collection is in EPSG:32632 coordinate reference system and it is located somewhere in this bounding box:

```
xMin, yMin 470701.73,5048820.54 : xMax,yMax 641679.97,5165204.84
```

Filter uses polygons expressed in EPSG:4326, but usign org.geotools ReprojectingFeatureCollection this is not a problem. Here are the two polygons:

```
the_geom bbox POLYGON ((-180 -90, -180 90, 0 90, 0 -90, -180 -90)),
the_geom bbox POLYGON ((0 -90, 0 90, 180 90, 180 -90, 0 -90))
```

who are respectively reprojected into:

```
the_geom bbox POLYGON ((-108523640.02189268 -187176133.93183675, -108523640.02189268 187176133.93183675, 274812009.447262 187176133.93183675, 274812009.447262 -187176133.93183675, -108523640.02189268 -187176133.93183675)), 
the_geom bbox POLYGON ((-69745878.65576684 -187176133.93183675, -69745878.65576684 187176133.93183675, 274812009.447262 187176133.93183675, 274812009.447262 -187176133.93183675, -69745878.65576684 -187176133.93183675))
```

What I expect is that applying filter with the first polygon I should get no features and when I apply filter with the second polygon I should get all the features. It's strange that filter gives back the whole features when is applied with both polygons! Here is a test to reproduce

```
public class FilterTesting {

@BeforeClass
public static void setUp() {
  System.setProperty("org.geotools.referencing.forceXY", "true");
}

@Test
public void filterTesting() throws Exception {
  String file = "whereisyour.shp";
  FileDataStore ds = FileDataStoreFinder.getDataStore(new File(file));
  SimpleFeatureCollection features = ds.getFeatureSource().getFeatures();
  ReprojectingFeatureCollection rfc = new ReprojectingFeatureCollection(features, org.geotools.referencing.CRS.decode("EPSG:4326"));
  Filter filter = buildFilter(-180D, -90D, 0D, 90D);
  SimpleFeatureCollection fc = rfc.subCollection(filter);
  Assert.assertTrue(fc.isEmpty());
  filter = buildFilter(0D, -90D, 180D, 90D);
  fc = rfc.subCollection(filter);
  Assert.assertFalse(fc.isEmpty());
}

private BBOX buildFilter(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2) throws Exception {
  FilterFactory2 ff = CommonFactoryFinder.getFilterFactory2(null);
  ReferencedEnvelope bbox = new ReferencedEnvelope(x1, x2, y1, y2, 
  CRS.decode("EPSG:4326"));
  return ff.bbox(ff.property("the_geom"), bbox);
}
}
```

I am using org.geotools version 17.2.

***UPDATE***

You can download a shapefile to reproduce the behavior [here](https://www.dati.lombardia.it/download/7bu5-xfs6/application/zip)

Comment: remember how we discussed axes order yesterday - you are still using lon,lat instead of lat,lon. Also it's much more efficient to project the bbox instead of all the data.

Comment: Also with out some input data it's impossible to reproduce this issue to check that my instinct is right

Comment: @iant hello. Sorry but I can't provide the data. You suggest to remove system property and invert filter's polygons x with y, right?

Comment: just some data that looks like yours would do, but I would project the bbox and compare the coordinates with the ones in your data

Comment: I'll try to provide some data (newbie at Qgis). About axes order: using system property helped on tile rendering but raise a problem about filtering..

Comment: @iant hello, I provide a link to some data I used to reproduce filter's behavior. Please check update, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you can't reproject your filter into EPSG:32632 as it exceeds the valid domain of the projection. I'm surprised that you aren't seeing an exception too.

By definition your projection is only valid in the range 6.0E 0.0N -
12.0E 84.0N - so when you (or the `reprojectingFeatureCollection`) tries to reproject your bounding boxes it goes off to infinity at the Pole.

So I'm not sure what you are trying to do but I think you need to reconsider how you are doing it.